# What kind of classifier is used in the following scenario?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

If I am building a weather predictor that will predict if it is will snow tomorrow, it is very easy to just straight away answer by saying "NO".

Obviously, if you evaluate such a classifier on every day of the year, it would be correct with an accuracy at 95% (considering that I build it and test it in a region where it snows very rarely).

Of course, that is such a stupid classifier even if it has an accuracy of 95% because it is obviously more important to predict if it will snow during the winter months (Jan & Feb) as opposed to any other months.

So, if I have a lot of features that I collect about the previous day to predict if it will snow the next day or not, considering that there will be a feature that says which month/week of the year it is, how can I weigh this particular feature and design the classifier to solve this practical problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Of course, that is such a stupid classifier even if it has an accuracy of 95% because it is obviously more important to predict if it will snow during the winter months (Jan & Feb) as opposed to any other months.

Accuracy might not be the best measurement to use in your case. Consider using [precision, recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) and [F1 score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score).

> how can I weigh this particular feature and design the classifier to solve this practical problem?

I don't think **you** should weight any particular feature in any way. You should let your algorithm do that and use [cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) to decide on the best parameters for your model, in order to also avoid overfitting.

If you say jan and feb are the most important months, consider only applying your model for those two months. If that's not possible, look into giving different weights to your **classes** (going to rain / not going to rain), based on their number. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621518/what-is-the-difference-between-class-weight-none-and-auto-in-svm-scikit-learn/28625807#28625807) discusses that issue - the concept should be understandable regardless of your language of choice.