# Role of class_weight in loss functions for linearSVC and LogisticRegression

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, logistic-regression

I am trying to figure out what exactly the loss function formula is and how I can manually calculate it when `class_weight='auto'` in case of `svm.svc`, `svm.linearSVC` and `linear_model.LogisticRegression`.

For balanced data, say you have a trained classifier: `clf_c`. Logistic loss should be (am I correct?):

```
def logistic_loss(x,y,w,b,b0):
    '''
    x: nxp data matrix where n is number of data points and p is number of features.
    y: nx1 vector of true labels (-1 or 1).
    w: nx1 vector of weights (vector of 1./n for balanced data).
    b: px1 vector of feature weights.
    b0: intercept.
    '''
    s = y
    if 0 in np.unique(y):
        print 'yes'
        s = 2. * y - 1
    l = np.dot(w, np.log(1 + np.exp(-s * (np.dot(x, np.squeeze(b)) + b0))))
    return l
```

I realized that logisticRegression has `predict_log_proba()` which gives you exactly that when data is balanced:

```
b, b0 = clf_c.coef_, clf_c.intercept_
w = np.ones(len(y))/len(y)
-(clf_c.predict_log_proba(x[xrange(len(x)), np.floor((y+1)/2).astype(np.int8)]).mean() == logistic_loss(x,y,w,b,b0)
```

Note, `np.floor((y+1)/2).astype(np.int8)` simply maps y=(-1,1) to y=(0,1).

But this does not work when data is imbalanced.

What's more, you expect the classifier (here, logisticRegression) to perform similarly (in terms of loss function value) when data in balance and `class_weight=None` versus when data is imbalanced and `class_weight='auto'`.  I need to have a way to calculate the loss function (without the regularization term) for both scenarios and compare them.

In short, what does `class_weight = 'auto'` ***exactly*** mean?  Does it mean `class_weight = {-1 : (y==1).sum()/(y==-1).sum() , 1 : 1.}` or rather `class_weight = {-1 : 1./(y==-1).sum() , 1 : 1./(y==1).sum()}`?

Any help is much much appreciated.  I tried going through the source code, but I am not a programmer and I am stuck.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 6):

### `class_weight` heuristics

I am a bit puzzled by your first proposition for the `class_weight='auto'` heuristic, as:

```
class_weight = {-1 : (y == 1).sum() / (y == -1).sum(), 
                1 : 1.}
```

is the same as your second proposition if we normalize it so that the weights sum to one.

Anyway to understand what `class_weight="auto"` does, see this question:
[what is the difference between class weight = none and auto in svm scikit learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621518/what-is-the-difference-between-class-weight-none-and-auto-in-svm-scikit-learn).

I am copying it here for later comparison:

> This means that each class you have (in classes) gets a weight equal
>   to 1 divided by the number of times that class appears in your data
>   (y), so classes that appear more often will get lower weights. This is
>   then further divided by the mean of all the inverse class frequencies.

Note how this is not completely obvious ;).

This heuristic is deprecated and will be removed in 0.18. It will be replaced by another heuristic, `class_weight='balanced'`.

The 'balanced' heuristic weighs classes proportionally to the inverse of their frequency.

From the docs:

> The "balanced" mode uses the values of y to automatically adjust
>   weights inversely proportional to class frequencies in the input data:
>   `n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y))`.

`np.bincount(y)` is an array with the element i being the count of class i samples.

Here's a bit of code to compare the two:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.utils import compute_class_weight

n_classes = 3
n_samples = 1000

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=n_samples, n_features=20, n_informative=10, 
    n_classes=n_classes, weights=[0.05, 0.4, 0.55])

print("Count of samples per class: ", np.bincount(y))
balanced_weights = n_samples /(n_classes * np.bincount(y))
# Equivalent to the following, using version 0.17+:
# compute_class_weight("balanced", [0, 1, 2], y)

print("Balanced weights: ", balanced_weights)
print("'auto' weights: ", compute_class_weight("auto", [0, 1, 2], y))
```

Output:

```
Count of samples per class:  [ 57 396 547]
Balanced weights:  [ 5.84795322  0.84175084  0.60938452]
'auto' weights:  [ 2.40356854  0.3459682   0.25046327]
```

### The loss functions

Now the real question is: how are these weights used to train the classifier?

I don't have a thorough answer here unfortunately.

For `SVC` and `linearSVC` the docstring is pretty clear

> Set the parameter C of class i to class_weight[i]*C for SVC.

So high weights mean less regularization for the class and a higher incentive for the svm to classify it properly.

I do not know how they work with logistic regression. I'll try to look into it but most of the code is in liblinear or libsvm and I'm not too familiar with those.

However, note that the weights in `class_weight` **do not influence directly methods such as `predict_proba`**. They change its ouput because the classifier optimizes a different loss function.
Not sure this is clear, so here's a snippet to explain what I mean (you need to run the first one for the imports and variable definition):

```
lr = LogisticRegression(class_weight="auto")
lr.fit(X, y)
# We get some probabilities...
print(lr.predict_proba(X))

new_lr = LogisticRegression(class_weight={0: 100, 1: 1, 2: 1})
new_lr.fit(X, y)
# We get different probabilities...
print(new_lr.predict_proba(X))

# Let's cheat a bit and hand-modify our new classifier.
new_lr.intercept_ = lr.intercept_.copy()
new_lr.coef_ = lr.coef_.copy()

# Now we get the SAME probabilities.
np.testing.assert_array_equal(new_lr.predict_proba(X), lr.predict_proba(X))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for getting back, and thanks for your thorough explanation about the weights!  so according to the first version: w0 = 2*n_1 / (n_0+n_1) and w1=2*n_0/(n_0+n_1) where w0 is weight of class 0, n_0 is number of samples in class 0 and n_1 is number of samples in class 1.  Super strange heuristic.  Maybe I am not understanding something clearly, but the newer version that you referenced also amounts to the same weights (at least for the binary case).  I also found this discussion which may be helpful to other readers too: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4324

Comment: And I see.  The weighting scheme is not incorporated in `predict_proba()` or `predict_log_proba()`.   :'-(    But perhaps I can incorporate it by sth like this:  `loss_imbalanced = loss_balanced[indices_of_class_0] * w0 + loss_balanced[indices_of_class_1] * w1`.  I will try this and post the results.

Comment: Don't be sad ;). Note that the 'balanced' heuristic is different even if the binary case. Consider `y=[0, 0, 1]`, you'll get : `auto:  [ 0.66666667  1.33333333]` and `balanced:  [ 0.75  1.5 ]`. As for `predict_(log_)proba()` it is fairly straightforward to wrap the function into something that uses weights.